# Objective-C Blocks and variable scope

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I would like to set the value of an `NSData` object within my block. Can someone let me know what I have done wrong here?

```
// Data
__block NSData *data = nil;

[ZSURLConnection performRequestWithUrl:wsdlURL xmlString:xml completionHandler:^(NSData *response, NSError *error) {

    // Handle the error
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        data = response;
    }//end

}];//end block

if (data) {
    NSString *d = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"DATA --- %@", d);
}

return data;
```

Why can't I assign the response to `data` and then retrieve it outside of my block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the block runs asynchronously, *after* the rest of your method. Either rewrite your calling code to work with the asynchronous loading, or find a way to perform the block's work synchronously. I don't know what `ZSURLConnection` is, but check to see if it has a version of the "perform..." method that doesn't run in the background.

Comment: So there is no way to make a wrapper for a request like this that returns an `NSData` object?  I will always have to use a delegate?

Comment: If you make a wrapper, you'll need to run it on a background thread since you cannot block the main thread. In most cases that is less efficient and just as much code. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

`performRequestWithUrl:xmlString:completionHandler:` is not a synchronous method. It sets up an asynchronous request and then immediately returns. The rest of your method runs and returns.

When the request completes, only then does it run your block, which assigns `data` and then immediately throws it away.

Were this a synchronous method, your routine would block pending an expensive network operation. Were this on the main thread, your entire app would hang. `ZSURLConnection` (and `NSURLConnection`) is designed to avoid that.