# How do I use a variable outside of a GET request?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, networking, afnetworking

**I would like to**:

- Initialise a variable prior to an GET request (AFNetworking)
- Assign to the variable inside the request success
- Use the variable once request is done

---

**The error I get:**

- When trying to do something the variable after the GET request, it breaks, claiming there is no value to the variable yet

---

The following is my code, how do I solve this problem?

```
- (IBAction)synchronisePressed {
    //Would like to initialise a variable here
    __block NSArray *received;
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager   GET:@"http://foo.com/foo/"
        parameters:nil
           success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
               //Assign responseObject to received object
               received = responseObject;
               NSLog(@"Woo: %@", @"got here");
           }

           failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
               NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
           }];
    //Now outside of request, so use array in some way
    [foo received];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C Blocks and variable scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407675/objective-c-blocks-and-variable-scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the code or in the request. The problem is the `GET` method of AFNetworking is asynchronous and you are trying to use it synchronously.

This means that the `GET` method will start working and sit in the background working away and the rest of your code will continue as normal. Only when the `GET` request has finished will the code inside the blocks get run.

This code be 1 second or 30 seconds or any amount of time after you start the request.

Put in an `NSLog` before your line `[foo received];`.

The order of logs will be like so...

```
1. Created NSArray called received.
2. Pass NSArray called received to method foo.
// some time later
3. AFNetworking GET request finished.
4. Assign value from the GET request to the NSArray called received.
```

What you need to do in this case is put your call to `[foo received];` INSIDE the completion block.

Something like this...

```
- (IBAction)synchronisePressed
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    [manager   GET:@"http://foo.com/foo/"
        parameters:nil
           success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
               //Assign responseObject to received object
               NSArray *received = responseObject;
               NSLog(@"Woo: %@", @"got here");
               [foo received];
           }

           failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
               NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
           }];
}
```

Now you will get...

```
1. Created NSArray called received.
// some time later
2. AFNetworking GET request finished.
3. Assign value from the GET request to the NSArray called received.
4. Pass NSArray called received to method foo.
```

Comment: No idea why I didn't think of this, I was going round in circles over-engineering. Thanks :) As a side, how much code would be required to make this synchronous? If it's possible at all.

Comment: I would avoid synchronous networking code. By doing it synchronously it will block the main UI thread. This means that if your network request takes 10 seconds then the app will freeze completely for 10 seconds. If your app does anything that will take a "human perceivable" amount of time then do that task asynchronously.